# Gapps script on removing rows when a cell contains a certain text stops working after the first 800~ rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this script here on a spreadsheet with over 3000 rows and 24+ columns.

When I execute this script, it runs fine for the first minute, then it just stops working.

I refresh my spreadsheet, then run script again. The previous deleted rows are gone, and it starts to execute again.

After a few seconds, and a few more rows deleted, it says the Script is Finished, but I clearly see more rows with the word Kitten in them.

If I run the script again, it will delete more rows with the word Kitten. Then it will say the Script has Finished, when clearly, there are more rows with the word Kitten in the cell.

I have to keep on running the script over and over to finally remove all instances.

This spreadsheet has a bunch of data ranging from queries, pivots, import ranges e.g.

Maybe it is a size issue?

Was Gaaps script ever intended to be used for files this large? (3000+rows with 24 columns of data in each row).

If so, any way to optimize? Maybe a way to run the script using UI on a selected range using a mouse?

```
function deleteRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var values = s.getDataRange().getValues();

for (var row in values)
  if (values[row][3] == 'Kittens')
  s.deleteRow(parseInt(row)+1);
};
```

Comment: Have you reviewed the execution transcript? Is there any error message or hint about why your script is finishing before the 6 minutes execution time limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably exceed the Script runtime, see [Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas).Think a way around the problem.
What you're trying to accomplish is not deleting rows containing the word 'Kittens', but filter range values that don't contain 'Kittens'.

```
function filterDataRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var range = s.getDataRange();
  // Get row and column of first cell in range
  var firstRow = range.getRow();
  var firstCol = range.getColumn();
  var values = range.getValues();
  // Filter values in column 4 using a custom function
  values = values.filter(filterKittenInCol4);
  // Clear data range
  range.clear();
  /* Get the filtered data range:
       - first cell is the same as the old range
       - values.length = numRows
       - values[0].length = numColumns
     and set the values */ 
  s.getRange(firstRow, firstCol, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
};

function filterKittenInCol4(e) {
  return e[3] != 'Kittens'; 
};
```

Comment: When running this script, I've noticed that it removed all of my formulas, and made this a plain text only spreadsheet. How do I retain my formulas after running the script?

My formulas were able to be retained when using my first script.

Comment: Didn’t know there were formulas on you sheet. The sample code above gets a big values array, it filters it, clears the range and sets the values. You could set the formulas again with [.setFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulas(String)) method. Another approach could be using [.sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object)) to have the ‘Kittens’ cells consecutive and then [.deleteRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer)).

Comment: Using `.deleteRows(rowPosition, howMany)` it's way faster than having `.deleteRow(rowPosition)` removing rows repeatedly.